# Adding data to existing JSON file with react native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm trying to add some new data to an existing JSON file from text input.
I use React Native and I store some data in JSON file called PartyInfo.json, when I fill out a form I want the data will be passed and stored in the PartyInfo.json file.

```
const PartyInfo = require('../PartyInfo.json');

let party = {
        name: this.state.name,
        info: this.state.info,
        date: this.state.date,
        price: this.state.price,
    };
    let data = JSON.stringify(party);
    PartyInfo.writeFile('PartyInfo.json', data);
```

I have tried to follow some answers to similar questions but nothing worked...
thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use file system:https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs or you can also use `AsyncStorage`

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/write-json-file

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install npm i react-native-fs
 using **npm i react-native-fs** and use below code to update your file

```
 var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

    var filePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/YOUR_FILE_NAME';

    RNFS.writeFile(filePath, YOUR_TEXT, 'utf8')
      .then((success) => {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
```

Comment: I have just tried that, it shows me the "Success" message but the input does not append to my JSON file... any ideas?

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: Make sure you understand where it's writing the file to. Log out the RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath, if you're testing locally it will be somewhere in the DerivedData folder.